# Delete top row in Android SQlITE database

Tags: android, sqlite, row, sql-delete

Currently I have this code in my program:

```
public void delete(String id, String name, String phonenumber, String time, String message)
{

    String[] args={id};

    getWritableDatabase().delete("texts", "_ID=?", args);
}
```

It works fine, and deletes the specified row. However, I also want to implement it so that I can delete the most recent (earliest date) entry in the database, which should be at the top of the table. I know I can do this by altering the last 2 parameters of delete, but I cannot figure out what to change them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`order by` and `limit` clauses in SQLITE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Comment: I didn't even know this website existed. Thank you